# Precompiling Handlebars with grunt-contrib-handlebars version issue

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js

I've just tried setting up the precompiler for grunt and handlebars. I'm getting this error accessing my template:

```
Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>= 4.0.0) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (>= 2.0.0-beta.1).
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, i think that plugin is out of date for Grunt. Feel free to correct me if I"m wrong.

I used `grunt-shell` and just used the shell to compile them (after using node to update the version of handlebars)....

```
shell: {
        options: {
            stderr: false
        },
        handlebars: {
            command: 'node_modules/handlebars/bin/handlebars src/templates/*.handlebars -f dist/js/templates.js'
        }
    },
```